# upgraded to 2.9 bool shortcuts changed?

Tags: modifiers, shortcut

I've just updated to 2.9, and can't use the `Ctrl numpad -` shortcut to make a bool difference anymore, manually adding a modifier works fine. The `emulate numpad` option isn't checked.

Has the shortcut changed? I can't see any difference in the documentation regarding bools.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My first time upgrading, I didn't realise I had to re-enable add-ons.

The issue was resolved by `edit > preferences > add-ons` then reactivating `Bool-Tool`.